# Screen saver crashes if UAC is enabled

Tags: crash, uac, manifest, screensaver

Does screen saver require any manifest file? I'm renaming the .exe to .scr file.

Right now i am not using any manifest file for the screen saver. But if if UAC is enabled, my screen saver crashes. How to by pass this UAC thing ?

Comment: Does the screen saver really need admin privileges? What does it do?

Comment: Fredrik, it loads a dll which does serialize/de-serialize, registry read/write and some other things. And that particular DLL requires admin privilege actually

Answer (score 0):

It's rather the point that you can't (well, shouldn't be able to, at least).

Presumably, you're accessing some resource that requires elevated privileges, and then not checking whether you successfuly obtained it.

Does UAC actually bring up a dialog?

Comment: David, no it doesn't show any uac dialogue and what i guess is when Windows runs the .scr file it chooses "Don't Allow" from the UAC dialogue. Cause, if I double click .scr file and choose "Allow" from the UAC dialogue it runs without any problem.